# Ways to select 3 members from 5 candidates

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> At an election there are 5 candidates and 3 members are to be selected. In how many ways a voter can vote?

My attempt: 1st member can be chosen in 5 ways, 2nd in 4 and 3rd in 3. So, $5*4*3=60$.

But the answer is given as 25. And the hint says $C(5,1)[C(3,1)+C(2,1)].$ I am not getting it.

Comment: Let's say the candidates are named $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ and $e$. Then yes, there are $60$ different ways the election can go, but keep in mind that $a$ then $b$ then $c$ results in the same members as $b$ then $c$ then $a$. So many of your $60$ are re-countings of the same resulting comittee. How many times is each _actually different_ result overcounted?

Comment: The actual answer should be 10. The only ways three officials can be selected out of five candidates are as follows (each number represents a candidate):

\begin{align*}
1,2,3\\
1,2,4\\
1,2,5\\
1,3,4\\
1,3,5\\
1,4,5\\
2,3,4\\
2,3,5\\
2,4,5\\
3,4,5\end{align*}
There is no other way.

Comment: yeah i got 10 too

Answer (score 1):

Your answer double counts possible permutations of the three selected candidates. For example, you are counting $$\quad A, B, C,\quad A, C, B,\quad B, A, C,\quad B, C, A,\quad C, A, B,\quad \text{and}\; C, B, A$$ as six separate possible choices, and yet they all represent precisely the same three candidates.

We could use your calculation, but then divide by $3! = 6$ to account for these permutations:

$$\dfrac{5\cdot 4 \cdot 3}{3!} = \dfrac{60}{6} = 10$$

Shorter yet, we have $5$-choose-$3$ ways a voter can select candidates: $$\binom{5}{3} = \frac{5!}{3!2!} = 10$$

---

In order to obtain an answer of $25$, you would need to assume that a voter has the option to vote for at least one candidate and at most three candidates.

Comment: So, as per your interpretation also, a voter votes thrice. But maybe a voter can vote only once. I am not sure. Just trying to guess from the hint given in question. May I know what your answer would be if a voter votes only once?

Comment: If a voter can vote only once, there are five candidates, so he/she can cast a vote in only one of five ways: for candidate $A, B, C, D, $ or $E$.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but if you could explain the hint given in the question, that would be very helpful. I mean in what case would that hint be applicable. I am assuming as per the given question, your answer is correct. But maybe the question-setter had something else in mind, so the different hint.

Comment: ya, i double checked. even some persons are getting the right answer but i am not able to get hints from them. See [here](http://www.pagalguy.com/forums/quantitative/official-quant-thread-cat-2013-t-88456/p-17714633/r-17717161).

Comment: If a voter can choose at least one candidate, and up to but no more than $3$ candidates, then there are $25$ possible ways a voter can vote: $$\underbrace{\binom 53}_{\text{cast 3 votes}} + \underbrace{\binom 52}_{\text{cast 2 votes}} + \underbrace{\binom 51}_{\text{cast 1 vote}} = 10 + 10 + 5 = 25$$

Comment: If casting less than three votes is allowed, then there are actually $26=\sum_{k=0}^{3}{5\choose k}$ ways, including not voting for anyone.

Comment: @triple_sec If you noted, the $25$ given by the answer will work if and only if a voter must vote for *at least one* candidate, and at most 3. Did you see my qualification above: "If a voter can choose at least one candidate, and up to but no more than 3 candidates..."

Comment: @amWhy Fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to get 25 as result:

Assume that you have the option to vote for a maximum of 3 candidates. Then you have 10 = 5-choose-3 = 5*4*3 / 3! options for voting for exactly three candidates, 10 = 5-choose-2 = 5*4 / 2! for voting for two candidates, and 5 = 5-choose-1 options for voting for only one candidate. The grand total is 25 options for voting for at least one and at most 3 out of 5 candidates.

Unfortunately, I cannot make sense of the hint right away, so I can only offer the guess that there is another way to think of this problem. If I had to give a hint in this form, using the notation C(n,k) for n-choose-k, I'd have hinted C(5,3) + C(5,2) + C(5,1)

EDIT: Added 5-choose-k equalities as explanation and a paragraph about (how little my answer related to) the hint.

Answer (score 0):

The condition is that a voter can't vote for more than $3$ candidates. But, he is entitled to vote for even $1$ candidate.
Thus, $5C1 + 5C2 + 5C3 = 25$. Why we add them is for the reason that, a voter can vote for one candidate or two candidates or three candidates. So we get $25$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).